# Computer always beeps when Ctrl and Shift pressed together

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

I have almost everything keyboard-related in the accessibility settings in Windows disabled and I still can't stop the OS from beeping every time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are pressed together.

I'm not sure or don't think it's related to "sticky keys".

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how I can stop it?

Comment: Just beeps, or does something happen as well? What make/model PC is this? (Might help to mention on your other question too.)

Comment: Just beeps. Haven't noticed any other behavior. It's a custom built PC. I can provide full system specs if necessary.

Comment: Under `Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use` if everything's disabled (i.e. Mouse/Sticky/Toggle/Filter Keys) I don't really see anything else that would make the PC beep with a single Ctrl+Shift combo. Some software might be responsible I guess. What's getting loaded at startup? Have you tried disabling everything? Does the issue occur in Safe Mode too?

Comment: Does it do this with other keyboards?  If not, maybe your keyboard has some kind of macro or special function for the ctrl+shift combination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was caused by a program called "Game Companion" which I had previously used to force games that didn't natively support borderless windowed mode into that display configuration. It was running at startup and had hotkeys for taking screenshots which would cause a beep whenever a screenshot was saved.

Comment: Along with the beeping, Game Companion also causes all sorts of weird hotkey behavior, like Ctrl + Backspace minimizing applications. I totally forgot I was using this program, so the symptoms were driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because, as you have found out: **Sticky Keys are enabled**

Go in Control Panel>Keyboard and disable from there.

Comment: Except Control Panel->Keyboard has no options for Stick Keys in Win 7 and I already said in the question that it's disabled in the Accessibility Settings.

Comment: enable it, see how it does then and disable it again. if it still bother you... throw the computer out the window :)) this is very odd!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same problem as you but I just found out the solution!
Go to Control Panel > Sound > choose Sounds tab > Default Beep. If you click Test there you should be hearing the same sound it always make when you press CTRL + SHIFT. So just change the tone to (none) and apply the setting.
I hope it works for you as well